# How can i modify the design of Line Chart using ng2-chart?

Tags: angular, ng2-charts, ng2-bootstrap

[image]

This is  my current chart which i created using ng2-charts library.
It can give me my data  output as popup on mouse hover.

Instead of this i need fixed block  which contain my company logo  and name.
I don't have any idea how to modify this html.

[image]

For getting list of companies at given stage,

```
callbacks: {
        title: function (tooltipItems, data) {
          return (tooltipItems[0] || {})['xLabel'];
        },
        label: function (tooltipItems, data) {
          let dummyValue : any[] = [
                                      {id:123, user: "Test  Data 1", stage: "Stage 3"},
                                      {id:456, user: "Test  Data 2", stage: "Stage 3"},
                                      {id:789, user: "Test  Data 3", stage: "Stage 6"},
                                      {id:147, user: "Test  Data 4", stage: "Stage 6"}
                                    ];
          let result = [];
          dummyValue.forEach(element => {
            if (tooltipItems.xLabel === element.stage) {
              result.push(element.user);
            }
          });
          return result;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom tooltip by using the `custom` property and adding a callback function.

E.g. Add `tooltips` property to your ng2-charts `ChartOptions`:

```js
tooltips: {
      enabled: false,
      custom: 
      function(tooltipModel) {
                // Tooltip Element
                var tooltipEl = document.getElementById('chartjs-tooltip');

                // Create element on first render
                if (!tooltipEl) {
                    tooltipEl = document.createElement('div');
                    tooltipEl.id = 'chartjs-tooltip';
                    tooltipEl.innerHTML = '<table></table>';
                    document.body.appendChild(tooltipEl);
                }

                // Hide if no tooltip
                if (tooltipModel.opacity === 0) {
                    tooltipEl.style.opacity = 0;
                    return;
                }

                // Set caret Position
                tooltipEl.classList.remove('above', 'below', 'no-transform');
                if (tooltipModel.yAlign) {
                    tooltipEl.classList.add(tooltipModel.yAlign);
                } else {
                    tooltipEl.classList.add('no-transform');
                }

                function getBody(bodyItem) {
                    return bodyItem.lines;
                }

                // Set Text
                if (tooltipModel.body) {
                    var titleLines = tooltipModel.title || [];
                    var bodyLines = tooltipModel.body.map(getBody);

                    var innerHtml = '<thead>';

                    titleLines.forEach(function(title) {
                        innerHtml += '<tr><th>' + title + '</th></tr>';
                    });
                    innerHtml += '</thead><tbody>';

                    bodyLines.forEach(function(body, i) {
                        var colors = tooltipModel.labelColors[i];
                        var style = 'background:' + colors.backgroundColor;
                        style += '; border-color:' + colors.borderColor;
                        style += '; border-width: 2px';
                        var img = '<img width="20" height="20" style="background-color:pink; margin-right: 6px;" >';
                        var span = '<span style="' + style + '"></span>';
                        innerHtml += '<tr"><td>' + img  + span + body + '</td></tr>';
                    });
                    innerHtml += '</tbody>';

                    var tableRoot = tooltipEl.querySelector('table');
                    tableRoot.innerHTML = innerHtml;
                }

                // `this` will be the overall tooltip
                var position = this._chart.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

                // Display, position, and set styles for font
                tooltipEl.style.opacity = 1;
                tooltipEl.style.position = 'absolute';
                tooltipEl.style.left = position.left + window.pageXOffset + tooltipModel.caretX + 'px';
                tooltipEl.style.top = position.top + window.pageYOffset + tooltipModel.caretY + 'px';
                tooltipEl.style.fontFamily = tooltipModel._bodyFontFamily;
                tooltipEl.style.fontSize = tooltipModel.bodyFontSize + 'px';
                tooltipEl.style.fontStyle = tooltipModel._bodyFontStyle;
                tooltipEl.style.padding = tooltipModel.yPadding + 'px ' + tooltipModel.xPadding + 'px';
                tooltipEl.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
                tooltipEl.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.8)';
                tooltipEl.style.color = 'rgb(255,255,255)';
            }
    },
```

You can change the `<img>` tag to add in your company logo as a `src` attribute in this line:

`var img = '<img width="20" height="20" style="background-color:pink; margin-right: 6px;" >';`

Here's my codepen for you to explore: [**Codepen link ⚡**](https://codepen.io/NotJohn/pen/oNNmOyQ)

Comment: Hey @terahertz, I checked your code on both places(put in my code and also check link) but it is not reflect any change. Can you describe more brief how it works?

My current need is just create one dynamic box at each  of chart  data points.

Comment: tooltipEl.querySelector('table') value return null response in both place. And this code  is not as per  my requirement i need fixed html block not on-hover popup

Comment: Hmm... my bad, your picture had misled me with that line linking to the data point. _I have edited my codepen_, could you take a look? Is that what you are trying to accomplish? The company name and company image has **nothing** to do with your dataset, am I right? Do let me know if that's what you want and I will edit my answer later

Comment: Thank you so much @terahertz for giving your valuable time, I checked your code pane it somehow like i want but not exactly. Your designed block is right but i need this block in each of my data point when page load. For more detail i provide another image.

Comment: Actually data of the company(name & logo) i got from back-end, i filter them based on stage value(which i already done) and print those filtered data on relevant stage data point's box. I also provide one default json of company data.

Comment: so how is this "panel" of company data shown? You had said it's not supposed to be shown on hover (of each data point) earlier but you want it to be next to every data point. Your graph is going to become very cluttered if you display this "company panel" for every data point. Anyway, descriptive information like your previous comment should be intially included in your question.... .... If anything, you should have designed your wireframes and confirmed your interactions before setting out to code.

Comment: I mean to say I already got data on hover(not image) but my requirement to show some fix box beside every data point which show both company name and logo on page load and not editable. I edited my question check image and default json